# Ubuntu doesnt see my Kindle (4th generation) as mtp device

Tags: 14.04, usb, mtp, kindle

My kindle 4th generation was working for a year just fine just plugging it in with a USB- microUSB cable and transferring the books with calibre.
Now since a couple of weeks it does charge but it doesnt get mounted so i cant put new books inside.
Libmtp, mtptools, mtpfs and calibre are installed and updated.
I've tried using different cables, with the same result.

Output from

```
lsusb:
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 1949:0004 Lab126, Inc. Amazon Kindle 3/4/Paperwhite
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 0458:0035 KYE Systems Corp. (Mouse Systems) 
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:63fe Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0a5c:5800 Broadcom Corp. BCM5880 Secure Applications Processor
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

tail -f /var/log/syslog 
Nov 19 16:13:11 umberto-Latitude-E4300 kernel: [ 1852.449264] usb 2-4: SerialNumber: 90231702303704BC
Nov 19 16:13:11 umberto-Latitude-E4300 kernel: [ 1852.458309] usb-storage 2-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Nov 19 16:13:11 umberto-Latitude-E4300 kernel: [ 1852.458523] scsi9 : usb-storage 2-4:1.0
Nov 19 16:13:11 umberto-Latitude-E4300 mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 6: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-4"
Nov 19 16:13:11 umberto-Latitude-E4300 mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 6 was not an MTP device
Nov 19 16:13:12 umberto-Latitude-E4300 kernel: [ 1853.458528] scsi 9:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Kindle   Internal Storage 0100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
Nov 19 16:13:12 umberto-Latitude-E4300 kernel: [ 1853.460546] sd 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
Nov 19 16:13:12 umberto-Latitude-E4300 kernel: [ 1853.471200] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
Nov 19 16:14:15 umberto-Latitude-E4300 wpa_supplicant[1140]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
Nov 19 16:14:31 umberto-Latitude-E4300 kernel: [ 1932.004114] usb 2-4: USB disconnect, device number 6
Nov 19 16:14:52 umberto-Latitude-E4300 kernel: [ 1953.224192] usb 2-4: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
Nov 19 16:14:52 umberto-Latitude-E4300 kernel: [ 1953.369481] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=1949, idProduct=0004
Nov 19 16:14:52 umberto-Latitude-E4300 kernel: [ 1953.369494] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Nov 19 16:14:52 umberto-Latitude-E4300 kernel: [ 1953.369502] usb 2-4: Product: Amazon Kindle
Nov 19 16:14:52 umberto-Latitude-E4300 kernel: [ 1953.369508] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: Amazon
Nov 19 16:14:52 umberto-Latitude-E4300 kernel: [ 1953.369514] usb 2-4: SerialNumber: 90231702303704BC
Nov 19 16:14:52 umberto-Latitude-E4300 kernel: [ 1953.378882] usb-storage 2-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Nov 19 16:14:52 umberto-Latitude-E4300 kernel: [ 1953.379125] scsi10 : usb-storage 2-4:1.0
Nov 19 16:14:52 umberto-Latitude-E4300 mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 7: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-4"
Nov 19 16:14:52 umberto-Latitude-E4300 mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 7 was not an MTP device
Nov 19 16:14:53 umberto-Latitude-E4300 kernel: [ 1954.378678] scsi 10:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Kindle   Internal Storage 0100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
Nov 19 16:14:53 umberto-Latitude-E4300 kernel: [ 1954.386515] sd 10:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
Nov 19 16:14:53 umberto-Latitude-E4300 kernel: [ 1954.388893] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

thanks a lot!

Comment: Is the usb_storage module loaded?  You seem to missing three lines after the (first) "not an MTP device"  

[1876.097964] usb-storage 3-2:1.0: Mass Storage device detected  

[ 1876.098673] scsi7 : usb-storage 3-2:1.0  

[ 1876.098834] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage

Comment: Marc - according to this bug report on the libmtp website, your kindle isnt an mtp device - are you sure you were using mtp?  Try switching on mass-storage on the kindle.  http://sourceforge.net/p/libmtp/bugs/518/

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the following commands:

```
sudo mount /dev/sg2 /mnt
cd /mnt
ls
```

Then paste here the output.